# How can I change color of collapse menu?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am trying to learn Bootstrap. I took the example navbar from the documentation, which is:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-primary">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <div>
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Then I added this to my CSS file:

```
.navbar-collapse {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

However, the width of the collapse menu isn't 100% of the screen so the left and right side of the collapse menu do not change when I do this. I can remove the padding of the whole navbar but that messes up everything and I feel like there should be an easier way to do this. Is there really or should I just suck it up and adjust everything separately after removing the padding?

Comment: Your question title mentions color but the post body is all about size. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to add a negative margin and then counteract with padding...

```
.navbar-collapse {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/11BVJBneqS)